# Should I ask about graduate school recommendations on Academia.SE?

Tags: discussion, support

I would like to ask about recommendations for graduate school in a mathematics (combinatorics).

Can I ask about this on Academia.SE? Or, would this be an Math.SE question?

Comment: A very closely related question, "I've been admitted to various Ph.D. programs, how do I choose between them?" was chosen to receive a canonical answer: http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/questions/3269/canonical-qa-suggestion-ive-been-admitted-to-multiple-graduate-programs-how which provides great suggestions for this type of situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this would be off topic on Academia. Questions asking for recommendations or comparisons of graduate programs would be closed as a *shopping question*, per the [help center](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

I don't know whether or not it would be on topic on Mathematics. I suspect not.